# liptables ssh rule is not working

Tags: iptables, netcat

I have 2 virtual machines using virtual box. One virtual machine work as a router. Im trying to drop all communications entering the router machine, excpet for some services. The interfaces ips that I have in each machine are:

Virtual machine 1 that work as router:

```
eth1: 193.136.200.254 
eth2: 10.10.0.254 
eth3: 10.254.0.254
```

Virtual machine 2:

```
eth1: 10.10.0.2 
eth1:0: 10.10.0.3 
...
```

I want to accept ssh connections to the router if originated at the machine with ip 10.10.0.3. So in the router machine I define the rules:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.10.0.3 -d 10.10.0.254 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

And now Im trying to test if this is working using netcat. So in the router machine Im running the command:

```
nc -l 10.10.0.254 22
```

And in the virtual machine 2 Im running:

```
nc 10.10.0.254 22
```

Then I write a random word in one machine but it is not appearing in the other machine. So it isnt working. Do you know what is wrong?

If I test this netcat commands before put the policy with drop it works, what I write in one machine appears in the other machine.

The result of iptables -L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt      source        destination
ACCEPT     tcp  ---      10.10.0.2     10.10.0.254     tcp dpt:ssh
```

Comment: Can you post the result of 'iptables -L'?

Comment: Your VM has both `10.10.0.2`, and `10.10.0.3` and I am betting they are both in the same subnet.  Why are you expecting that the source address seen by the router will be 10.10.0.3 and not 10.10.0.2?  What happens if you change your rule to `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.10.0.0/24 ...`

Comment: Thanks for your help. With that command it works. But I just want accept from the 10.10.0.2 machine.

Comment: iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.10.0.3,10.10.0.2 -d 10.10.0.254 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your solution should do the same as the 10.10.0.0/24. But what I want is to accpet only from the 10.10.0.2 machine not also from 10.10.0.3.

Comment: Append a drop rule with a log target then you see what is dropped (and why). And use iptables-save to see all rules and chains and the resulting sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which source address is printed by tcpdump for the incoming netcat connection on port 22 from Virtual Machine 1?

On Virtual Machine 2:

```
iptables -F
tcpdump -n -i eth3 'port 22'
```

Maybe the default route on Virtual Machine 1 is bound interface eth2 causing all outgoing traffic on that subnet to have the source address of that interface.

What does the output of `route -n` show on Virtual Machine 1?

Comment: With that command it seems that the traffic is going to another interface is going to eth1 and not eth1:0. But the 10.10.0.2 is the eth1:0, do you know how to change the rule to do this?

Comment: `ip route add 10.10.0.254 src 10.10.0.3` 

or add the `-s` parameter to your netcat to define the source address to use (on Virtual Machine 2):

`nc 10.10.0.254 22 -s 10.10.0.3`